# @media css внешний файл

Tags: css, media-queries

Доброго времени суток всем. Вообщем начал я изучать @media и возникло много вопросов, но не могу найти в интернете не чего ну или плохо ищю)
Возможно ли подключить @media во внешнем файле типо

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"> - основной файл 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/device.css"> - для телефонов
```

и внутри device.css прописать

`@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}`

и писать все что хочу изменить этого разрешения
сам пробовал так сделать не чего не происходит 
в чем проблема? или же нельзя отдельным файлом так сделать?
делал так в основном файле и все работало, но хочется красиво в отдельном

Comment: Можно! И должно работать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так делать.

Проверьте если файл подключился. Если подключился проверьте применяются-ли все стили.

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте ссылку:
   а. Существует файл по ссылке (проверить можно с помощью инструментов веб-браузера)
   б. Содержит ли файл тот код, какой необходим. ( Возможно кэш или вы редактируете другой файл и т.п);
2. Наличие в HTML-документе между тегами head следующая строка.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`